# How To Test For Default Selected Option - KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

### The Problem

I have a **SELECT** field that holds client names.  When you choose a client, a text field is populated with the client's email.

[image: Screen snippet of UI]

BUT... when the user selects the default option "SELECT CLIENT..." , the code fails. This is the error message I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="select" data-bind="options: clients,
                                  optionsText: 'full_name',
                                  optionsCaption: 'Select Client...',
                                  value: selectedClient
                                  ">
```

**ViewModel**

```
let ClientModel = function(id, full_name, email){
    this.id        = id;
    this.full_name = full_name;
    this.email     = ko.observable(email);
}


function CreateQuoteViewModel() {

   self = this;

    // Client Information
    self.email    = ko.observable();
    self.clients  = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedClient = ko.observable();

   /* GET CLIENTS FROM API */
   $.getJSON(apiCustomersAll,
    function(data) {
        var fullName;
        $.each(data,
            function(key, val) {
                fullName = val.first_name + " " + val.last_name;
                self.clients.push(new ClientModel(val.id, fullName, val.email));
            });
    });


    /* WHEN SELECT CHANGES ... */
    self.selectedClient.subscribe(function (newValue) {

        // Search CLIENTS Array, Find New Value
        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.clients(), function(item) {
            return item.id == newValue.id;
        });

        // Now, Populate Client Information
        if(newValue === null || newValue == undefined || newValue == ""){
            // Clear client information 
            self.email("");
        } else {
            self.email(match.email());

        }

    });


}


ko.applyBindings(new CreateQuoteViewModel());
```

As you can see, I am TRYING to catch this error, but I am still getting an error.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Everything works fine unless they choose the default option.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Move the  `var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(...);` inside the `else` block. Currently, you are accessing `newValue.id` even if `newValue` is undefined

Comment: Thanks Adiga! That appears to work. My logic was flawed, I just didn't see it. Now, of course, it makes perfect sense. I'd like to accept your answer, can you please convert your comment to an answer somehow?

Comment: You're welcome. You can probably delete it as it was a simple error and it's unlikely to help anyone in the future :)